# SQL Server DATEPART() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Today I wrote two queries on `Datepart()` and get different returns below

Query #1:

```
Select Datepart(day,'2015-07-05')
```

returns '5', which I expected.

Query #2:

```
Select Datepart(day, 2015-07-05)
```

Returns '27', which is a little bit funny, and I don't understand how 27 is being returned.

The difference between these two queries is one with the date inside ' ', and the other without.

Anybody can help me out here?

Answer (score 5):

`2015-07-05` is just a mathematical expression which adds up to the integer 2003. (Subtracting 7 from 2015 gives 2008 then subtract 5)

2003 evaluates to `'1905-06-27'` when implicitly cast to datetime as casting `int` to `datetime` works the same as adding that number of days to the base date of 1 Jan 1900 (i.e. equals  `DATEADD(DAY, 2003,'19000101')`).

So this is where the 27 comes from.

The correct way to denote date literals in SQL Server is as a string `'2015-07-05'` (ISO format - unambiguous for newer datetime datetypes) or `'20150705'` (unambiguous for legacy datatypes) or using the [ODBC format](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234(v=sql.90).aspx) `{ d '2015-07-05' }`.